# How do I substitute symbols in a language object?

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following language object:

```
lang <- quote( f(x=a) )
```

and I want to substitute in `1` for `a`. How can I do this?

I would expect `substitute` to do what I want, but

```
substitute(lang, list(a=1))
```

just returns `lang`, while

```
substitute(f(x=a), list(a=1))
```

does in fact do what I expect.

Answer (score 5):

Use `do.call`:

```
do.call(substitute, list(lang, list(a=1)))
```

By using `do.call`, we force evaluation of the name `` `lang` `` to its actual underlying value, `f(x=a)`. Then substitution is performed on `f(x=a)`, rather than the name `` `lang` ``.

Comment: If your language object is a function call, you can update the argument defaults directly via: `lang$x <- 1`, `lang$x <- quote(b)`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you have previously defined `a` in some environment (`.GlobalEnv`) as:

```
a <- 1
```

You can generally run:

```
construct(deconstruct_and_eval(lang))
f(x = 1)
```

For the definitions of these custom functions, see [Generalized function to substitute all variables in the quote()d expression, if they exist in an environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328467/generalized-function-to-substitute-all-variables-in-the-quoted-expression-if/19347239#19347239)

Comment: I believe you need to run `require(data.table)` for this to succeed.

Comment: be aware that `deconstruct_and_eval` is not longer present in package source, it was removed in 1.9.7 so anyone looking for it should check 1.9.6

Answer (score 3):

You can use `substituteDirect` rather than `substitute`:

```
substituteDirect(lang, list(a=1))
```

Eventually you may be able to use `substitute`.  According to `?substituteDirect`:

> The goal is to replace this with an `eval=` argument to `substitute`.

Comment: How is this not in the `base` package? I see it's in the `methods`...