# Generalized function to substitute all variables in the quote()d expression, if they exist in an environment

Tags: r

Having similar problem, I am looking for a more generalized solution than the one provided for this question: [How do I substitute symbols in a language object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282610/how-do-i-substitute-symbols-in-a-language-object)

I have an unevaluated expression `foo <- quote(bar + baz)`, which is a variable inside other expression: `qux <- quote(bla + foo)`.

We can check that:

```
exists("foo", envir=.GlobalEnv) & class(foo)=="call"
[1] TRUE
exists("qux", envir=.GlobalEnv) & class(qux)=="call"
[1] TRUE
```

Now I would like to write a generalized function that decomposes (parses?) `qux` into the component expressions and **replaces** the ones that exist in the `.GlobalEnv` **and** that are of class `call` with their values:

```
replaceFUN <- function(x) {
  # do something
}
```

Running `replaceFUN(qux)` should return:

```
bla + (bar + baz)
```

**Background on the actual problem:**

I am building a quant trading rules backtesting engine. My aim is to delay evaluation of the quote()d expressions, such as rules and indicator calculations later after their definition.

```
require(data.table)
require(TTR) # for the `SMA` function

DT <- data.table(Instrument=rep("SPX",3),Date=1:3, Close=c(1050, 1052, 1051))

# define parameters
nSMA <-2
t <- 2

# define indicators
time.filter <- quote( Date==t )
moving.average <- quote( SMA(Close, nSMA) )    
buy <- quote( Close > moving.average & time.filter )


AddColumn <- function(x, colname) {
  DT[,eval(substitute(colname)):=eval(x, envir=.SD)]
}

AddColumn(time.filter, "filter")

    Instrument Date Close filter
 1:        SPX    1  1050  FALSE
 2:        SPX    2  1052   TRUE
 3:        SPX    3  1051  FALSE

AddColumn(moving.average, "MA")

   Instrument Date Close filter     MA
1:        SPX    1  1050  FALSE     NA
2:        SPX    2  1052   TRUE 1051.0
3:        SPX    3  1051  FALSE 1051.5

AddColumn(buy, "Buy")

Error in Close > moving.average & time.filter : 
operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

This obviously raises an error because `AddColumn` function lacks the mechanism to parse the nested `moving.average` and `time.filter` variables (plus and any other that user defines and nests). The nesting of rules inside `buy` is done for readability and is indeed a syntactic sugar.

Comment: In your case: `do.call(substitute, list(qux, list(foo=foo)))`

Comment: Thanks Joshua, that certainly helps to solve the substitution part of the problem. Another part of the problem is how to decompose `qux` expression into components to search for in the `.GlobalEnv` and for the matches to populate the list in `do.call(substitute, list(qux, list(foo=foo)))`. First thing that came to mind was `strsplit()`, but I don't know the `split` argument in advance. Maybe I should edit my question to break down the problem into parts.

Comment: Instead of breaking the question into parts, perhaps you should give some background on the actual problem you're trying to solve. There's probably an easier way than searching for and substituting calls.

Comment: Look at how [quantstrat](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=316) handles delayed evaluation. Or, better yet, contribute to quantstrat rather than re-creating something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was solving a very similar problem to this a little while ago. Check out the [source code](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/data.table.R?view=markup&root=datatable) of `[.data.table` and look at the `deconstruct_and_eval` and `construct` functions there. It should give you enough info to go on.

Comment: spot on, I have amended the `deconstruct_and_eval` function that you pointed out and it works! See my detailed answer. It needed additional `eval` statement for the objects that exist in the environment and that are not functions. As your answer provided a crucial lead, I thankfully set this as accepted answer and provide tedious details in separate.

Comment: be aware that `deconstruct_and_eval` is not longer present in package source, it was removed in 1.9.7 so anyone looking for it should check 1.9.6

Answer (score 3):

Customizing this function from  [`[.data.table` source code](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/data.table.R?view=markup&root=datatable/)
yields the desired general solution:

```
deconstruct_and_eval = function(expr, envir = parent.frame(), enclos = parent.frame()) {

  if (!mode(expr) %in% c("call", "expression")) 
    return(expr)

  if (length(expr) == 1) {
    if (is.call(expr[[1]])) return (deconstruct_and_eval(expr[[1]]))
    else return(expr)
  }

  if (expr[[1]] == quote(eval) && length(expr) < 3) {
    return(deconstruct_and_eval(eval(expr[[2]], envir, enclos), envir, enclos))
  }

  lapply(expr, function(m) {
    if (is.call(m)) {
      if (m[[1]] == quote(eval)) eval(m[[2]], envir, enclos)
      else deconstruct_and_eval(m, envir, enclos)
    } else {
# begin edit 
      if(exists(as.character(m),envir=.GlobalEnv)) {
        if(!is.function(eval(m)))
           eval(m)
           else
             m
      } else
# end edit
        m
    }
  })
}
```

Running the function with the original question variables yields:

```
deconstruct_and_eval(qux)
[[1]]
`+`

[[2]]
bla

[[3]]
bar + baz
```

This deconstructed list can then be rebuilt with the `construct` function from [source code](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/data.table.R?view=markup&root=datatable/):

```
construct(deconstruct_and_eval(qux))
bla + (bar + baz)
```

**Application on the actual problem:**

```
deconstruct_and_eval(buy)
[[1]]
`&`

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
`>`

[[2]][[2]]
Close

[[2]][[3]]
SMA(Close, nSMA)


[[3]]
Date == t

construct(deconstruct_and_eval(buy))
Close > SMA(Close, nSMA) & Date == t
```