# substitute known variables in quoted expression

Tags: r, expression, eval, quote

I want to write a function *f* that given:

```
x <- 1  
f(.(y==x))
```

It returns the string:

```
"y == 1"
```

The function should be general enough, that the expression can be arbitrary.  For instance, `f(.(y==x & z==x))` should return `"y == 1 & z == 1"`.

Any ideas?

The function:

```
g <- function(e) as.character(unlist(e))
```

does not work for me, as it returns "y == x".  I want the replacement to take place.

**UPDATE:**

Also, this question is not a duplicate of [How do I substitute symbols in a language object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282610/how-do-i-substitute-symbols-in-a-language-object)  I want to create a function *f*, that means that somehow I need to get the value of *x* from the caller's environment.  My current attempt is this:

```
require(plyr)
x <- 1
f <- function(e) do.call(substitute, list(e[[1]], parent.frame(1)))
f(.(y==x & z==x))
```

But it still does not work.  Maybe I should use something else instead of `parent.frame`?

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe like this: `function(e) paste0("y == " , e)`?

Comment: @Jilber I think the input should be a valid R expression, but returned a character string.

Comment: helpful to know that `.` is a function from the `plyr` package.

Comment: `g <- function(e) eval.parent(e[[1]])` gets a little closer, but fails because it also tries to evaluate `y`

Comment: how about this: `g <- function(e) {substitute(e)}` and then manipulating the third element of `g(y==x)`

Comment: I don't think `substitute` gets us very far (unless I'm misunderstanding your point), but manipulating the third element is a good idea.

Comment: Is this what you want? `deparse(quote(y==x & z==x))` then output looks `[1] "y == x & z == x"`

Comment: @kohske: no that's not what I want.  The variables that exist in the environment should be replaced.  So, if `x=1`, then `f(.(y==x & z==x))` should return `"y == 1 & z == 1"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 library(plyr)
 g <- function(e) { 
      e[[1]][[3]] <- eval.parent(e[[1]][[3]])
      deparse(e[[1]]) 
 }
 x <- 1
 g(.(y==x))
```

This works, but is perhaps not as general as you wanted.  (I would rather have a solution that substituted values if possible and left the values alone otherwise.)

**UPDATE**: not working yet, but maybe helpful.

```
 g <- function(e) {
      e1 <- e[[1]]
      pe <- parent.env(environment())
      vars <- all.vars(e1)
      ss <- setNames(lapply(vars,
                   function(v) if (exists(v,pe)) get(v,pe) else v),
                     vars)
      ## at this point I'm stumped -- have tried various
      ## versions of eval, lapply, rapply, substitute ...
      ## afraid I would actually have to make up my own recursive
      ## function since rapply() only works on lists ...
 }
```

Comment: As you say, what I want to do is more general.  For instance, `f(.(y==x & z==x))` should return `"y==1 & z==1"`.  I am thinking about a way to recursively traverse the expression, replacing all the variables that exist in the environment for their values.  But don't have a solution yet.  It seems that the function `mget` should be part of the solution.

Comment: you should add these specifications to your original question.

Comment: what happens if `y` and `z` are defined in the original environment?  should they be replaced, or left alone because they are on the LHS of the expression?

Comment: I think the best is if anything that exists in the calling environment is replaced.

Comment: See my update to the question.  It seems that the function `substitute` does all of the replacement heavy lifting.  The question now is how to access the value of `x` in the caller's environment. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```r
f <- function(e) {
    deparse(do.call("substitute", list(e, as.list(parent.frame()))))
}

x <- 1
f(quote(y == x)) # "y == 1"
f(quote(y==x & z==x)) # "y == 1 & z == 1"
```

I use `do.call` to construct a `substitute` call that has the arguments in `args` evaluated. In the case of `f(quote(y == x))`, the call will be `substitute(y == x, list(x = 1, f = ...))`.
I have to use the **list** `as.list(parent.frame())` instead of the environment `parent.frame()` because according to `?substitute`

> If it is an ordinary variable, its value is substituted, unless env is .GlobalEnv in which case the symbol is left unchanged.

Calling `parent.frame()` inside `f` result in `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>`

I am not familiar with `plyr::.` so I use `quote` in base instead.