# substitute values and then output an expression

Tags: r, expression

I have an equation `a+bx`. I want a function in which when I input `a = 2` and `b = 4`, R automatically output `2+4x` as an expression. I do not how to do this in the programme R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be surprisingly tricky, and depends a bit on how your equation is stored.

If you don't need to store the equation (expression) in a symbol, this is not too bad:

```
f <- function(a,b) { bquote(.(a)+.(b)*x) }
f(2,4)
## 2 + 4 * x
```

If you have `ee <- expression(a+b*x)`, then you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282610/how-do-i-substitute-symbols-in-a-language-object) to get to

```
L <- list(a=2,b=4)
do.call(substitute, list(ee[[1]], L))
## or substituteDirect(ee[[1]], L)
## 2 + 4 * x
```

(I'm not 100% sure why you have to use `[[1]]` to extract the "body" of the expression, but you do.)

If you want to do this with multiplication denoted by juxtaposition (i.e. interpreting `a+bx` as `a+b*x`) that's going to be much harder ...

Comment: It seems to work fine. I was surprised how tricky the problem is. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `expression()` returns a collection like a list, so you need to use the `[[1]]` to extract the value from the list. In order to avoid that you can just use `ee <- quote(a+b*x)` so `ee` is a call and is the same as the value you get when subsetting the expression collection object.